# I would like to see a report of another user channel Youtube?? can I?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to see a report of another user channel Youtube??. what we can view the report by using another user with CHANNEL ID, where channel id that, i get from another user auth.

i see in doc:
channel==CHANNEL_ID – Set CHANNEL_ID to the unique channel ID of the channel for which you are retrieving data. The user authorizing the request must be the owner of the channel.

i try this:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DXXXXXXXXXX&start-date=2016-02-25&end-date=2016-03-30&metrics=views%2Clikes&dimensions=day&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

where XXXXXXXXXXX is channel ID another user. 
can I??

Answer (score 0):

You may retrieve YouTube channel reports with your given HTTP request upon the channel or content owner's authorization . You can also provide additional query parameters, such as dimensions, filters, and sorting instructions. However, please note that core dimensions and core metrics used in your query are subject to Deprecation Policy as defined in the [Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/dimensions#Core_Dimensions) and [Metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#Core_Metrics) documentations.

Comment: thanks for the response.
I mean how can I show the report to other users ?? in my case as famebit [dot] com, so a sponsor and creator, so the sponsor can see any report of content shared by the creator.
examples of such sponsorship can view reports from chanel youtuber (creator) as a demographic report, like and dislike report, audience retention etc from report (analytics).

how to make like famebit[dot]com??